# Find command with sed returns zero length but command has output

Tags: sed, find, cron

I can't get my head around why these commands won't work:

```
[ $(find /shares/Public -name *.scr -type f | sed "/.scr/a>removed | " >>/shares/Public/delete_scr.log) ] && (echo -e "$(date)\r\n" >>/shares/Public/delete_scr.log & find /shares/Public -name *.scr -type f -delete)
```

It's a crontab job that should remove files with the .scr ending and log each case on one line with a date in the end. But the script should only write to the log file if the find-command returns files.

I'm not strong at this and my tests suggest that $(find ...) returns a zero length string even though files are found. This means that a date is written to the log even though no files were found...

I have tried with ! -z and ! -n but I think I need to do it another way - but how?

Thanks,

Comment: do you get output for `find /shares/Public -name *.scr -type f`? if not try quoting... `find /shares/Public -name '*.scr' -type f`

Comment: Yes, I do get output for that - if one or more .scr file exist. If none exists the command returns nothing (apparently)...

Comment: I was wondering if it is because the output is redirected to a file and therefore not "output" as such... Will test without >>, but how do I go by that?

Comment: Hmmm, this line appears to be working:
[ $(find /shares/Public -name *.scr -type f) ] && (find /shares/Public -name *.scr -type f | sed "/.scr/a>removed | " >>/shares/Public/delete_scr.log & echo -e "$(date)\r\n" >>/shares/Public/delete_scr.log & find /shares/Public -name *.scr -type f -delete)
Is there a way to optimize that line - can I pass the output of the $(find)-command to sed without repeating the find-command?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is going on here, but I think you should check out `-exec` option of `find`.. check out this Q&A https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice ... there are links in there pointing to other examples of using find as well.. hope you'll find a way out :)